# Excel: Counting number of male and female employees

Tags: excel-formula

It might be a basic question but I'm struggling to come up with a function. I have two columns on a spreadsheet: Employee ID and Sex (Male=1). A sample data is as follows: [CAPTURE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ox5H.png)

[image]

Each data entry is an unique observation, and I want to count the number of males and females. For example, there are 2 females and 1 male employee out of 32 observations. What forumula can I use to calculate the numbers?

Comment: Make a new column for your count, click in the sex column, go to Data>Subtotal, choose Use Function: Count, add subtotal to: your new count column. Done.

Comment: I can't find the subtotal button. What do you mean by that? Do you mind giving me an example code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to add another column to hold whether or not the row is a duplicate or not, you can use the SUMIF function to add up the total number in your sex column (number of males) and compare it to your total duplicates.

Comment: Should I use SUMIF or SUMIFS? Could you give me an example code? You can assume the employee column is column A and the sex column is column B.

Comment: I would look at Scott Craner's answer above

Answer (score 0):

Use these array formulas:

Female:

```
=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$32=0,1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$32,$A$2:$A$32,$B$2:$B$32,0)))
```

Male:

```
=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$32=1,1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$32,$A$2:$A$32,$B$2:$B$32,1)))
```

being array formulas they need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Problem is, I'm trying to do the same thing for a column of size 20000+. But it seems to not work. Any comment on that?

Comment: Did you adjust the references to match your data?

Comment: I notice that for the Sex column, there are 0, 1, and blank values. Maybe the problem stems from this?

Comment: Please post the formula you are using, it should not matter if there are blanks in the Sex column.  You did use Ctl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: =SUM(IF(D2:D19033=0,1/COUNTIFS(C2:C19104,C2:C19104,D2:D19033,0)))

Comment: Notice that the lengths of D and C columns are different. I tried filtering out the blank cells and then run another code, but it didn't work.

Comment: The columns must be the same size, don't worry about blanks in Column D.  make them the same size.  COUNTIFS will not work with different size ranges. @sababi0314

Comment: =SUM(IF(D2:D19104=0,1/COUNTIFS(C2:C19104,C2:C19104,D2:D19104,0)))

Comment: I think you mean this, so that column D includes the blank cells and is the same size with column C. It still doesn't work...it gives me 0

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter?  Did Excel put `{}` around the formula?

Comment: Yes! I wish I could move this to chat, but it doesn't allow me to.

Comment: Then at this point I have no idea why it does not work.  Make sure the numbers in Column D are true numbers and not text.  After that I am stumped.

Comment: I copied and pasted the two columns to a new spreadsheet, and it worked. Thank you so much for your help, Scott!

Comment: @sababi0314 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.